# When is a method cached, and when is the cache invalidated?

Tags: perl, method-resolution-order

How does the Perl method cache work?

According to the documentation for [mro](https://perldoc.perl.org/mro.html):

> **`mro::invalidate_all_method_caches()`** Increments `PL_sub_generation`,
>   which invalidates method caching in all packages.
>
> **`mro::method_changed_in($classname)`** Invalidates the method cache of any
>   classes dependent on the given class.

When it is necessary to invalidate the method caching? Why is it done? It seems like in some cases it is invalidated for a single package (and its parents), and in other cases it is invalidated for all packages.

See also [Class::MethodCache](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::MethodCache)

Comment: Re "*When it is necessary to invalidate the method caching?*", Manually? Never, to my knowledge. XS modules may need to do that, but from Perl, adding/removing subs from a stash should already do that.

Comment: Re "*It seems like in some cases it is invalidated for a single package (and its parents), and in other cases it is invalidated for all packages.*", Correct. `HvMROMETA(stash)->pkg_gen++` vs `PL_sub_generation++`.

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/z93NciwH) demonstrates the caching. Perl literally copies the methods from the bases classes into the child classes to avoid having to look them up. But they are flagged as generated so that they don't override methods that are later added to the base classes (when a cache regeneration occurs).

Comment: If method cache invalidation is needed in pure-perl code, it would probably be considered a bug.